# javascript bring back variable in different function ; for use on the google bid by weather script

Tags: javascript

I have the following google adwords script that basically automatically adjusts the daily adword bid budget by bringing back the weather from wunderground (as the products are weather dependent)

It works fine and this might be an easy solution to some but this is not my language.

At the moment it brings back the live daily budget called (function called 'getBudget') from google adwords. What i want to do is bring back a daily budget from an excel sheet which i have already connected. You can see below from the excel sheet that it brings back the campaignname and locationname from the excel sheet. I have added that it brings back a third column called dbudget, which is does fine, however

My problem is this line

`if (keyword.getBudget()) {
      keyword.setBudget(keyword.getBudget() * bidMultiplier);  }
     }`

I want to bring back that variable (dudget) and use it here so it uses dbudget and not getbudget

i.e.

`if keyword.dbudget()) {
      keyword.setBudget(keyword.dbudget() * bidMultiplier);  }
     }`

But it does not work at the moment?

the script is

```
    ----------------

// Register for an API key at http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/
// and enter the key below.
var WEATHER_UNDERGROUND_API_KEY = "";

// Create a copy of http://goo.gl/IPZo3 and enter the URL below.
var SPREADSHEET_URL = "";


/**
 * The code to execute when running the script.
 */
function main() {
  var data = getSpreadsheetData(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var campaignName = row[0];
    var locationName = row[1];
    var dbudget = row[2];
    try {
      var weather = getWeather(locationName);
      Logger.log(format('Weather for {0} is {1} °F, {2} mph, and {3} in of rain. Current Daily Budget of £{4}',
          locationName, weather['temp_f'], weather['wind_mph'],
          weather['precip_today_in'], dbudget));
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log(format('Error getting weather for {0}: {1}', locationName, error));
      continue;
    }
    var bidMultiplier = getBidMultiplier(weather);
    if (bidMultiplier != 1) {
      Logger.log(format('Setting bids to {0}% for campaign "{1}"',
          Math.floor(bidMultiplier * 100), campaignName));
      adjustBids(campaignName, bidMultiplier);
    } else {
      Logger.log(format('No bid changes for campaign "{0}".', campaignName));
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Retrieves the campaign names and weather locations from the spreadsheet.
 * @param {string} spreadsheetUrl The URL of the spreadsheet.
 * @return {Array.<Array.<string>>} an array of campaign names and location
 *     names.
 */
function getSpreadsheetData(spreadsheetUrl) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var range =
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
  return range.getValues();
}

/**
 * Retrieves the weather for a given location, using the Weather Underground
 * API.
 * @param {string} location The location to get the weather for.
 * @return {Object.<string, string>} The weather attributes and values, as
 *     defined in the API.
 */
function getWeather(location) {
  var url = format('http://api.wunderground.com/api/{0}/conditions/q/{1}.json',
      encodeURIComponent(WEATHER_UNDERGROUND_API_KEY),
      encodeURIComponent(location));
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  if (response.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    throw format('Error returned by API: {1}', response.getContentText());
  }
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  if (!result['current_observation']) {
    throw format('Invalid location: {0}', location);
  }
  return result['current_observation'];
}

/**
 * Determines the bid multiplier to use based on the weather data.
 * @param {Object} weather The weather data to analyze.
 * @return (number) The bid multiplier to apply.
 */
function getBidMultiplier(weather) {
  // Higher score means higher bids.
  var score = 0;
  // Temperature.
  if (weather['temp_f'] < 30) {score-= 5;} 
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 30 && weather['temp_f'] <= 35 ) {score-= 4;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 36 && weather['temp_f'] <= 40 ) {score-= 3;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 41 && weather['temp_f'] <= 45 ) {score-= 2;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 46 && weather['temp_f'] <= 50 ) {score-= 1;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 51 && weather['temp_f'] <= 55 ) {score-= 0;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 56 && weather['temp_f'] <= 60 ) {score-= 0;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 61 && weather['temp_f'] <= 65 ) {score+= 1;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 66 && weather['temp_f'] <= 70 ) {score+= 2;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 71 && weather['temp_f'] <= 75 ) {score+= 3;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] >= 76 && weather['temp_f'] <= 80 ) {score+= 4;}
  else if (weather['temp_f'] > 81) {score+= 5;} 

  // Increase/decrease bid by 10% for each score point.
  return 1 + (0.1 * score);
}

/**
 * Adjusts the bids on all keywords in the campaign using the bid multiplier.
 * @param {string} campaignName The name of the campaign.
 * @param {number} bidMultiplier The bid multiplier to use.
 */
function adjustBids(campaignName, bidMultiplier, dbudget) {
  var selector = AdWordsApp.campaigns().withCondition(
      format('CampaignName = "{0}"', campaignName));
  var iterator = selector.get();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    var keyword = iterator.next();
    if (keyword.getBudget()) {
      keyword.setBudget(keyword.getBudget() * bidMultiplier);  }
     }


}

/**
 * Formats a string using "{0}" style placeholders.
 * @param {string} str The format string.
 * @param {...string} var_args The values to insert into the format string.
 * @return {string} The formatted string.
 */
function format(str, var_args) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length - 1; i++) {
    var reg = new RegExp('\\{' + i + '\\}', 'gm');
    str = str.replace(reg, arguments[i + 1]);
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to use a budget value from a spreadsheet that you have connected; instead of the budget value returned from the Google AdWords function.  Is that correct?

If so then what you will need to do is pass the dbudget value into the function from wherever you are calculating it and use that.

It seems you calculate dbudget inside of main() so you would pass it into adjustBids()

Since adjustBids already has dbudget in it's function declaration as a third parameter you won't have to change that.  Instead you would just change the call to adjustBids (from main function)

```
adjustBids(campaignName, bidMultiplier, dbudget);
```

and then change the adjustBids function like so:

```
if (dbudget) {
  keyword.setBudget(dbudget * bidMultiplier);
 }
```

Keeping in mind that this assumes you are maintaining a 1:1 relationship with the Campaign Names in your Spreadsheet to the Campaign Names that the Google Ad function will return.  If there is a mismatch there things could get...odd.

Comment: Thanks Dogoferis, thats exactly what i was after and works well